# Using getElementsByTagName and getAttribute methods

Tags: javascript

I have combined the `getElementsByTagName` and `getAttribute` methods to get the title attribute of every paragraph element in the document. Here is the code:

```
var paras = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (i = 0; i < paras.length; i++) {
    console.log(paras[i].getAttribute('title'));
}
```

The line of code I am specifically need assistance with is this one:

```
console.log(paras[i].getAttribute('title'));
```

What is the `[i]` doing within this line of code? Is this the 'counter' variable that I declared in the `for` loop that is incrementing on each iteration? And is the `[i]` also representative of the index of the array that is returned by the `getElementsByTagName` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key here is [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

You are then looping over the NodeList (which can be thought of as an array) with you for loop.  The value of `i` goes from `0` to the length of the array -1.

So to answer your question.  Yes, `i` is the index and when you say `paras[i]` you are asking for the element at index `i`.

For example, given the following html:

```
<body>
  <p id="a"></p>
  <p id="b"></p>
  <p id="c"></p>
</body>
```

If you called `paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p")` it would return an array with 3 elements.

- At `paras[0]` would be the p with id a.
- At `paras[1]` would be the p with id b.
- At `paras[2]` would be the p with id c.

Comment: Note that `getElementsByTagName` actually returns a `NodeList`, not a real array. But it has a `length` property so behaves mostly like a real array (but you can't do `paras.forEach`, for example).

Comment: @JamesAllardice You are right, I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are right.
paras is actually an array object of all p tags in the DOM containing all particular properties

you can run in chrome developer tools and see for your self

Answer (score 2):

As James already said, yes and yes.

`.getElementsByTagName` returns an array. You can access each item in that array by using an index, for example:

```
paras[0]
```

Accesses the first element (indexes start at 0 in JavaScript - but be careful, some languages start at 1).

```
paras[1]
```

Accesses the second item, and so on...

It's a common pattern to use a for loop to iterate through all elements in an array so you can do something to each item. So:

```
paras[i]
```

Accesses the *i* th element in your array.

Answer (score 1):

the getElementsByTagName return an array. so, you can access each element by the index. example:

```
paras[0]; // first <p> in your document
paras[1]; // second <p> in your document
paras[2]; // third <p> in your document
paras[3]; // fourth <p> in your document
```